# Fast mean of all elements in 1000 lists: return 1 value

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I have a data.frame with 10,000 lists each containing 1000 numbers. I would like to calculate the mean (and SD) of all the data together for a R shiny app and would like to find the fastest way of doing this. It should just return 1 mean and 1 SD value. Can anyone suggests a method please?

## Example data

```
    df<-data.frame(Risk=runif(10000))

df<-df %>%
    rowwise()%>%
    mutate(NumInfected = list(rbinom(n=1000, size = 1000, prob = Risk/100)))
```

This produces a data.frame with nested lists each containing 1000 values.

Comment: can you please give a [mre] please, at least show us a small sample of your data?  Do you really mean that the data frame contains lists, e.g. `d <- data.frame(a=I(list(1:3)),b=I(list(2:4)))`? or do you just have a regular 10000 x 1000 data frame containing numeric values?  In any case `d2 <- unlist(d); c(mean(d2), sd(d2))` should be pretty fast ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you, I appreciate it needs an MRE. To be transparent I've added an example of where the data comes from which produces nested lists.

Comment: And, have you tried Ben's suggestion? `d2 <- unlist(d$column); c(mean(d2), sd(d2))` is quite fast. Do you really need to go faster than that? It seems unlikely that that calculation is actually a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Sorry everyone, a is df, my mistake

Comment: No you're right @GregorThomas. Ben's results is very fast. I was just hoping that I wouldn't have to store the unlisted vector separately in memory but I guess that's a separate issue.

Comment: The slow part is getting the vector out of the `list` structure. So it's better to temporarily store the vector in memory and compute `mean` and `sd` on it then to extract it from the list separately for each `mean` and again for `sd`.

Comment: You could probably shave a few microseconds if you wrote C++ code that computed the mean and sd in one pass (i.e. stored the mean for the sd computation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `unlist` on the column and then computing the mean and sd takes about 0.1 seconds on my machine. Is that fast enough?

```r
ms <- function(df, col="NumInfected") {
   u <- unlist(df[[col]])
   return(c(mean(u), sd(u)))
}
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ms(df))
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 ms(df) 80.77705 84.43235 89.39736 89.0652 89.61738 149.7114   100
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. You're right it's not the bottleneck. I think mostly its the constant subsetting of data.